# Why do the Buddhists in India claim that Diwali is a buddhist festival?

Tags: history, festivals, buddhism, non-hindu

I am not sure whether it is a question to be asked on this forum but I have come across a lot of Navayani Buddhist online who claim that Diwali was a festival started by Mauryan Emperor Ashoka as Deepotsava and later became diwali.

Why is it that they claim so? Is there any documentation of the same or is it just a propaganda against us hindus?

Answer (score 1):

Pure Propoganda. None of Ashoka's edicts talk about any Deepotsava. This is just one of the many new anti-hindu propogandas.

Comment: Is there any counter to such nonsense then?

Comment: It's nonsense by some ambdkerite just leave em be better they stay in delusion.